Nadav and Avihu versus Titus the Wicked entering the Holy of Holies
There are commentaries (for example the Yalkut Shimoni on Torah 524:7) that explain that the sin of Nadav and Avihu was that they entered the Holy of Holies. This is just one opinion, and that is not the point here. What I was wondering was the following.
Rabbi Shimon HaKohen, over at Yeshiva.org mentions the Talmudic principle of "אֵין שׁוֹטֶה נִפְגָּע" (Shabbos 13b) - a fool is not hurt.
Rabbi Kohen then quotes a Midrash Rabbah (Vayikra Rabbah 20:5) which relates the following story:

The Holy One blessed be He said: ‘Will Aaron’s sons not be like his staff, that entered dry and emerged moist?’ The wicked Titus entered the chamber of the Holy of Holies with his sword drawn in his hand, stabbed the curtain, and his sword emerged full of blood. He entered in peace and emerged in peace. Aaron’s sons entered to sacrifice and emerged burned. That is what is written: “After the death of the two sons of Aaron, [when they approached before the Lord and they died].”

He quotes Rabbi Yitzchak Shelmkish of Galicia and explains that:

כשאדם נכנס לבית הכנסת, עליו להרגיש כיצד יראה של רוממות עוטפת אותו, הלוא הוא נכנס כעת אל הקודש, "בְּבֵית אֱלֹקִים נְהַל
When a person enters the synagogue, he must feel how an awe of exaltation envelops him, he is now entering the Holy of Holies, "the house of G-d" (loose translation).

Says Rabbi Kohen, Titus the Wicked was lacking this feeling. He did not feel any enthousiasm in entering the most holy place.

טיטוס נכנס אל הקודש ויצא ממנו, והדבר לא הותיר בו שום רושם. הבעיה כאן היא לא של הקודש, הבעיה כאן היא בגברא, יש כלל 'אין שוטה נפגע' , טיטוס הוא שוטה, הוא לא שייך אל הקודש ולכן הוא לא נפעל ממנו.


נדמה לי שבדברים הנפלאים הללו של רבי יצחק שמלקיש, רמוז עניינה של כל הפרשיה שלפנינו. פרשיית סדר העבודה מוקדשת לביאה אל הקודש, "בְּזֹאת יָבֹא אַהֲרֹן אֶל הַקֹּדֶשׁ" , לא מוזכר בה יום הכיפורים אלא ברמז אף על פי שכל הפרשיה עוסקת ביום הכיפורים, כי מה שחשוב כעת להזכיר זה שכניסה אל הקודש דורשת הכנה ראויה, לא בכל עת ניתן לבוא אל הקודש, צריך להתכונן. אדם שנכנס אל הקודש צריך לדעת מהן המגבלות של העולם החומרי שהוא נמצא בו, מנגד מהו הגודל של המציאות האלקית, ולבסוף עליו לזהות היכן היא נקודת החיבור, מתי ראויה הנשמה הישראלית להיכנס אל הקודש מבלי להיפגם. לא להיות כמו בני אהרן שהדבקו בשורשם ועלו למעלה, אלא להתגדל ולהתפעל ויחד עם זאת להישאר שייכים לעולם הזה. יש כאן שיעור יסודי שמברר כיצד אנו נדרשים להדבק בקב"ה.
פרשת העריות

I have trouble understanding this explanation. I really like it, but it is hard for me to get hold on the idea that is conveyed here. Sure, Nadav and Avihu, as the Chiddushei HaRim says, were  righteous individuals, wanting to perform G-ds service. On the other hand, Titus, was extremely wicked and defiled the holy place.
So, according to the above mentioned explanation, when a person feels that he is entering "the House of G-d", and his soul is connected on high, he is punished when defiling the Temple and when entering in the Holy of Holies and getting too close to G-d (there are also ideas that this was not the case anymore, because the Shechina left). However, when a rasha does this (a wicked person), he is not punished. Does this makes any sense?
Are there any sources that explain this another way, or is someone able to explain this in a more easy-to-understand way?

See perek Aleph Nefesh Hachaim

@LaniedSofey I found this one?

@LaniedSofey so, according to this, the man’s heart/mind corresponds to the interior of the Holy of Holies. But Titus was not "אדם מעם הקדש", but he defiled the Temple and the inner chambers. So why would it only matter when a holy person did it, and not when a rasha did it?
